# Trouble with $.post ans php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having troubles with that. I'd like to compare a variable that I send to a php script, like that.

```
var var1 = true;
var var2 = false;
$.post('script.php', {variable1: var1, variable2: var2}, function(data){
   echo "Testing";
});
```

Then, in 'script.php', I have something like that:

```
if($_POST['variable2'] == true){
   echo "Testing";
}
```

And the problem is that the script inside the if statement executes. I can't imagine what is happening, because when I print the array $_POST, I get this:

```
Array(['variable1'] => true ['variable2'] => false)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try using === instead of ==

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) and you'll see probably that false is actually 'false'

Comment: @dvidsilva that would not work with $_POST values since they are always sent as strings, not booleans, so the condition would never be true.

Comment: you could try: `$_POST['variable2'] === 'true'`

Comment: That's what I was wondering, variable2 is probably a string that has false in it as text, and a string of text is a truty.

And  ( 'true' === true  ) false or (true === 'false') false, but ( 'false' == true ) true

Comment: @Mike you're right, I put == 'true' and it worked.

Comment: @Mike The $_POST values are always sent as strings? Even in html forms? Or just in $.post?

Comment: I tried to set 1 or 0, instead of set true and false in the javascript, then i didn't have to modify to `if($_POST['variabel2'] == 'true')`, and it worked ok.

Comment: @user3260711 it doesn't matter how you send it to the server, whether an HTML form or JavaScript. Anything that goes into both `$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays are strings. PHP does not automatically convert them to anything else. Take a look at [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to see why what is in the `if` statement is being executed.